# Vue.js validator isn't showing errors

Tags: vue.js

**Here's the prop's validator:**

```
props: {
    task: {
      id: {
        type: Number,
        validator: function(value) {
          if (value < 5) {
            console.log("error");
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        }
      }
```

**here's the data I'm sending:**

```
export default {
  name: "tasklist",
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [
        {
          id: 1}
```

According to the validator I made I shouldn't have it to pass without a warning.
And I don't get any warning does anyone knows what I can do to get an error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a `validator` or specify the `type` of a specific property of a component's `prop` like you are trying to do.

You can specify the `type` of the `task` prop as `Object`, and then add a `validator` function to validate the type and value of the `task` object's `id` property.

Here's an example:

```js
Vue.component('task', {
  template: `<div>{{ task.name }}</div>`,
  props: {
    task: {
      type: Object,
      validator(task) {
        if (typeof task.id !== 'number') {
          console.error("error: task id should be a number");
          return false;
        }
        
        if (task.id < 5) {
          console.error("error: task id should not be less than 5");
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <task :task="{ name: 'foo', id: 1 }"></task>
  <task :task="{ name: 'bar', id: '9' }"></task>
  <task :task="{ name: 'baz', id: 6 }"></task>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was wondering if there was a way to block it instead of it just showing the error.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? Block what?

Comment: I meant is there a built in way to block the insertion as it seems the validation fails I wished it wouldn't insert it if it doesn't respect the condition let's say if the "id" is > 2 don't insert the id.

Comment: That's a separate question, but no. There is no built-in way to prevent a component from being created if its prop validation fails. You could simply put the check in a `v-if` on the root element of the component (`<div v-if="task.id >= 5">`)